# What can cause Bones in Armature to change despite the poseBone.Matrix being the same?

Tags: armature

I have an armature that is in a bindpose. I apply different matrices as bonepose.matrix with location scale and rotation in it at different times and frame them.

When I print out the matrix values the values are the same at frame 1 and at the last frame.
But the armature behaves strangely at frame 1, not on the other frames. but at frame 1 it has a different pose than at the last frame this despite me applying the same matrices.

What can cause this?